# With what to replace the deprecated line2d_seg_dist function of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering if there's anything to replace the deprecated [mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.line2d_seg_dist](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.line2d_seg_dist.html) function. There's no mention of it on the documentation page and I'm not entirely sure how to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just put the function into your code:

```
def line2d_seg_dist(p1, p2, p0):
    """distance(s) from line defined by p1 - p2 to point(s) p0

    p0[0] = x(s)
    p0[1] = y(s)

    intersection point p = p1 + u*(p2-p1)
    and intersection point lies within segment if u is between 0 and 1
    """

    x21 = p2[0] - p1[0]
    y21 = p2[1] - p1[1]
    x01 = np.asarray(p0[0]) - p1[0]
    y01 = np.asarray(p0[1]) - p1[1]

    u = (x01*x21 + y01*y21) / (x21**2 + y21**2)
    u = np.clip(u, 0, 1)
    d = np.hypot(x01 - u*x21, y01 - u*y21)

    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `3.1.0` API changes documentation, there's no replacement and the recommendation is to vendor said functions if you need them i.e. do what @ImportanceOFBeingErnest said.

```
Multiple internal functions that were exposed as part of the public API of mpl_toolkits.mplot3d are deprecated,

mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d

mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.norm_angle()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.norm_text_angle()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.path_to_3d_segment()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.paths_to_3d_segments()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.path_to_3d_segment_with_codes()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.paths_to_3d_segments_with_codes()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.get_patch_verts()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.get_colors()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.zalpha()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d

mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.line2d()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.line2d_dist()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.line2d_seg_dist()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.mod()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.proj_transform_vec()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.proj_transform_vec_clip()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.vec_pad_ones()
mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d.proj_trans_clip_points()
If your project relies on these functions, consider vendoring them.
```

Comment: Yeah, *"do what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said"* is the generic answer to everything, apart from 42 of course.

Comment: What exactly is "vendoring"?

Comment: Vendoring is the act of making your own copy of the 3rd party packages your project is using. Those copies are traditionally placed inside each project and then saved in the project repository.